# Web client not redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-client

I making a post with c# using webclient to send the visitor to a bank payment center. The issue is that the user never redirects to the link i would like to post. The code that i use for the webclient is:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["Value1"] = "test";
    values["Value2"] = "test";
    values["Value3"] = "test";
    values["Value4"] = "test";
    values["Value5"] = "test";
    values["Value6"] = orderid;
    values["Value7"] = "test";

    var response2 = client.UploadValues("https://mybanksite.com/redirection/pay.aspx", values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response2);
}
```

If i would use html form post i should use this form

```
<form action="https://mybanksite.com/redirection/pay.aspx" method="POST"> 
  <input name="Value1" type="hidden" value="test" /> 
  <input name="Value2" type="hidden" value="test" /> 
  <input name="Value3" type="hidden" value="test" /> 
  <input name="Value4" type="hidden" value="test" /> 
  <input name="Value5" type="hidden" value="test" /> 
  <input name="Value6" type="hidden" value="Test" /> 
  <input name="Value7" type="hidden" value="test" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Check out" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is didn't correct. What you get in your response 2 string. Are you debugging ang get some errors? Are you checkin SSL certificate to accesing HTTPS website?

Comment: You need to provide more info - what response are you getting when using web client, how the native request looks like. As it is currently written we can just guess.

Comment: have you tried adding a client certificate?